# Seaborn pairplot: vars and conditional elements

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, seaborn, var

In the dataset below some graphs will plot entries for (0,0).

```
import seaborn as sns
test_grid = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,10,20,30,40,50,60],'b':[0,60,50,30,20,40,80],'c':[10,40,70,30,50,80,0],'d':[50,60,80,100,50,80,0]})
sns.pairplot(test_grid)
```

1. How can I tell pairplot to ignore coordinates where x=0 and y=0 for any row in a given pairwise plot?

I'd like to do this in a conditional fashion with a combination of any two numbers- i.e. not by rebuilding the data frame with NaN to use dropna or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question in case someone finds it useful:

I haven't found a way to filter coordinates at the plotting level
so have instead sorted to filtering coordinates at the pandas level by generating a new DataFrame by applying multiple filters

```
test_grid_filtered = test_grid[(test_grid['a'] > 0) & (test_grid['b'] > 0)]
```

and then calling the plot